# Bash script to limit the number of logins

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

My company has the requirement that I have one server application running, which all users accessing it via  putty terminal. I want to write a shell script that only 20 putty terminal should be open. If 21st terminal open then I want to close that terminal immediately.

How can I achieve this?

Please help me.

Comment: Set the max number connections allowed access in ssh to 20 on the server in the `MaxSessions` field

Comment: If your corporation has a policy of 20 maximum sessions and the default is 10 (as the highest voted answer says), why did your company raise the number of allowable sessions > 20 in `/etc/sshd_config`, or is this a Ubuntu bug?

Comment: **If 21st terminal open then I want to close that terminal immediately** So the 20 first connections can hog the server indefinitely?

Answer (score 24):

Edit your `/etc/sshd_config` on the server side and change the line:

```
#MaxSessions 10
```

to

```
MaxSessions 20
```

See `man sshd_config`:

```
 MaxSessions
         Specifies the maximum number of open shell, login or subsystem
         (e.g. sftp) sessions permitted per network connection.  Multiple
         sessions may be established by clients that support connection
         multiplexing.  Setting MaxSessions to 1 will effectively disable
         session multiplexing, whereas setting it to 0 will prevent all
         shell, login and subsystem sessions while still permitting for-
         warding.  The default is 10.
```

Comment: yeah its works, bit late to add it as answer.

Comment: I've been meaning to setup SSSH thingy on one of my old laptops for awhile now. Is the man page saying that by default only 10 users can sign into the server? Even back in the 80's we could have a hundred users sign into an IBM S/36 mini-computer with 2 MB of RAM.

Comment: You are confusing sessions as in open terminals (see OP) with sessions inside a SSH connection. The setting you mention is about how many "sub-connections" are allowed by a single ssh-connection. So running 30 "ssh" commands is no problem even with ``MaxSessions 20``. The sessions mentioned there are about things like port-forwardings (and even having more than one shell open) using the same connection, not about the number of logins on the system.

Comment: @allo this information you got from OP?

Comment: @allo is correct here, MaxSessions refers to session multiplexing over a single TCP connection.  Unless all of OP's users are doing strange things to share a single TCP connection to the server this limit won't affect them.  I've just verified this myself by setting a low MaxSessions limit on a server and opening more than that many connections to it.

Answer (score 5):

George's solution works fine however you asked for a bash script...

So consider this one for other situations when there is no option like `MaxSessions` of `sshd`, then you can use something like this:

```
if [ "$(pgrep -cx processName)" -gt 20 ]; then pkill -xn processName; fi;
```

Which `pkill -n` will kill the newest instance of `processName`.

The correct solution for this special situation is George's answer.

Comment: Wouldn't this also prevent subprocesses?

Comment: Yeah it causes sub-process to be killed too.

Comment: Then -- given that bash forks lots of subprocesses, and they want to limit users, not processes -- this doesn't appear to be a useful answer.

Comment: @RonJohn It was a useful answer corresponding to the user requirements (A script that closes a process immediately) and for other users coming from search engines (a general answer to the title) until you edited the question.

Comment: Let me come in here. I also know that this place directs users to the right path based on the questions asked. If OP asks a question and the right answer (based on OP's question) isn't necessarily the best practice or right approach I think any one has the right to state this or give answers inline with that observation. I don't really think we should take the option of deciding what answer is the best let OP decide and I love to see many options from well informed site members. Please lets always have a constructive debate it helps me if not any other person!

Comment: *comments deleted*. Whoa there guys. Please keep discussions on topic and, above all, civil.

Answer (score 4):

I've decided to elaborate and test the [Ravexina](https://askubuntu.com/users/264781)'s [idea](https://askubuntu.com/a/1070139/566421). It works and it is effective if you want to restrict the number of established ssh connections at all.

First I found when the ssh daemon is running without any connection there is one `sshd` process. For each new connection two new `sshd` processes are created. So if you want limit of 20 connections the threshold should be **41** (1+2x20) instead of 20.

Then I've created an executable file, named `/usr/local/bin/limit-sshd`, that looks as follow:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$(pgrep -cx sshd)" -gt 7 ]
then
    echo '\nThe limit was reached!\n'
    pkill -xn sshd
fi
```

- The threshold here is 7, respectively only 3 connection could be established and the rest will be dropped.

Finally I've added the following directive to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```bsh
ForceCommand /usr/local/bin/limit-sshd; $SHELL
```

- The variable `$SHELL` will execute the default user's shell.
- An unwanted effect is that the greeting message is not longer available.
- Do not forget to restart the ssh daemon: `sudo systemctl restart sshd.service`

Here is how this works (*click on the image to see an animated demo*):

[image]

Further, I realised we do not need to kill anything, if we modify the script in this way:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$(pgrep -cx sshd)" -gt 7 ]
then
    echo '\nThe limit was reached!\n'
    exit # This line is not mandatory
else
    eval "$SHELL"
fi
```

And respectively `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in this way:

```bsh
ForceCommand /usr/local/bin/limit-sshd
```

Answer (score 2):

The question isn't clear. Let me tell first how do I understand it and in which way, IMO, it should be asked:

> We have local network where one server supplies a specific
>   application. Our team access this application via ssh connection from
>   their computers to the server by using PuTTY. Each team member has its
>   own user account that is used to establish the ssh connections (*or maybe:* all team members use a common user account).
>
> The team members doesn't use the server for any other purposes and we want to limit the number of their ssh connections to 20, no matter how much connections are established yet by a particular user (*or maybe:* 20 connections per user).

If that interpretation is correct, probably a correct way to fulfil the requirements is to create a *user group*, then add all user accounts to that group and limit the number of *maxlogins* via [`/etc/security/limits.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/limits.conf.5.html).

1. Create a group, called for example `the-app-maxlogins`, with group id `10 000`:

   ```
   sudo groupadd -g 10000 the-app-maxlogins
   ```
2. Add the users to that group - `sudo adduser <user> <group>`:

   ```
   for user in "user1" "user2" "user3"; do sudo adduser "$user" the-app-maxlogins; done
   ```
3. Add the next line to `/etc/security/limits.conf` to **limit** the maxlogins of **the entire group**:

   ```
   %the-app-maxlogins      -       maxlogins       20
   ```

   Or add the following line to **limit** the maximum logins number **per user of the group**:

   ```
   @the-app-maxlogins      -       maxlogins       20
   ```
4. Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and add the following lines to the bottom(!) of the file to disable session multiplexing for that group (probably this is not mandatory in that case):

   ```
   Match Group the-app-maxlogins
       MaxSessions 1
   ```

---

This solution will limit the number the logins of the affected users no matter through ssh or tty. If you want to apply it for a certain user not for a group just add a line as the follow in `limits.conf` or place it into a separate `.conf` file within the directory `/etc/security/limits.d/`:

```
username      -       maxlogins       20
```

---

Simple explanation of the actual meaning of the directive `MaxSessions` is provided in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28085/201297). The main source of the current answer is [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87532/201297) under the same L&U's question.

The [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1070294/566421) of mine, could provide workaround in some way, but it is a kind of fun rather than true solution.