# How do I configure my SSHD to use a different shell?

Tags: server, 18.04, ssh, sshd

**Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (Server)**

**Kernel: Linux 4.15.0-54-generic**

**Architecture: x86-64**

When I SSH into my box it uses the MOTD, PS2 and shell from my local profile of the server and what I'm looking for is a way that when I logon locally it's *zsh* and over ssh it's *bash*. I've looked in /etc/ssh/sshd_config for something about a prompt/shell but I'm not sure after that. Which other files would I put that distinction in?

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSH always uses the shell of the user it is logging in. The simplest way is to change your remote user shell to zsh:

```
usermod --shell /usr/bin/zsh YOUR_USERNAME
```

Other possibility is to use `ForceCommand` in `sshd_config`, which will run the `zsh` for you under the default shell (bash). But note, that this will actually prevent you from running any other commands directly, such as `scp` or `sftp`!

Comment: Here is example of `ForceComand` usage: https://askubuntu.com/a/1070294/566421. It could be combined with `Match User` directive: `https://askubuntu.com/a/905799/566421`.