# Allow SFTP file transfer over a severely limited SSH connection

Tags: ssh, sftp

For various reasons, I need to allow only one SSH connection to a server for a `specificuser` at a time, and when they log in, a command needs to be executed right away, limiting them in what they can do.

I thus created a script `/usr/local/bin/limit-sshd` (based on [this question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1070294/756440)) which is executed when an SSH connection is established (using `ForceCommand` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) and which, very simplified, looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $USER == specificuser ]]
then
    /run/this/command
else
    ...
fi
```

The use case for which this was created now includes file transfer to the server which you could typically achieve using an SFTP client such as `pscp`.

I am on a Windows machine using PuTTY and have a `configuration` for the server that I need to access; the configuration includes the sharing of the SSH connection. I can log in to the machine. On my Windows command line I then tried

```
pscp -load configuration c:\path\to\file_to_copy specificuser@<server IP>:/path/to/destination
```

This works with a user that does not have the limitations described above, but fails with

```
FATAL ERROR: Received unexpected end-of-file from server
```

I'm assuming this is due to the fact that there is some command passed via the SSH connection that the server cannot handle because of how I set things up above.

(How) can I enable file transfers over this connection?

Comment: Please describe how you attempted to "transfer a file using the existing SSH connection" with `pscp`

Comment: @steeldriver edited the question to make my use of `pscp` clearer

Comment: Thanks - what I was really interested in was the *configuration* - I guess you are doing this [Sharing an SSH connection between PuTTY tools](https://documentation.help/PuTTY/config-ssh-sharing.html), is that correct? Can you give us any information about what `/run/this/command` does?

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, I am sharing the connection. `/run/this/command` is a script that starts a Docker container inside which the `specificuser` can work, and which will be deleted after the user exits the container. The user needs to be able to load files from his own machine onto the server/into the container, ideally without a workaround like a Git repo or an Artifactory.